# Query regarding disk partitioning on windows 7

Tags: partitioning

I have 1TB hard disk and recently I had removed ubuntu from dual boot setup I had now I am trying to reformat it as NTFS and use it as windows disk but I run into error every time I try it

[image]

Comment: You need to remove the logical partitions inside the extended partition, then the extended partition itself. Then create one or more partitions with the file system you want. I strongly recommend you learn about partitions management before attempting advanced stuff like dual booting.

Comment: I didn't clearly understand some of it can you explain it more clearly or give me a link to a website explaining it